# Chai testing on React App returning unexpected result

Tags: testing, reactjs, mocha.js, chai

Hi I ran the following test and the test confirmed that `ChannelListItem` exists:

```
import React from 'react';
//import expect from 'expect';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from '../../src/common/store/configureStore';
import { shallow,mount } from 'enzyme';
import Channels from '../../src/common/components/Channels';
import ChannelListItem from '../../src/common/components/ChannelListItem';
import { fakeChannels } from '../fakeData/channelsFake';
import { fakeMessages } from '../fakeData/messagesFake';
const initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__;
const store = configureStore(initialState);
const socket = io('', { path: '/api/chat' });



describe('Channels', () => {
    const changeActiveChannel = sinon.spy()
    const dispatch = sinon.spy(store, 'dispatch')
    let Component;

    beforeEach(() => {

        Component = 
            shallow(<Provider store={store}>
                <Channels
                    socket = {socket} 
                    onClick = {changeActiveChannel}
                    channels = {fakeChannels}
                    messages = {fakeMessages}
                    dispatch = {dispatch}
                    />
            </Provider>);
    });

    it('should render', () => {
        expect(Component).to.be.ok;
    });


    it('should have a ChannelListItem', () => {
        const channelListItem = Component.find('ChannelListItem')

        expect(channelListItem).to.exist;
```

However, when I ran the following test, I got `channelListItem.length` equal 0

```
expect(channelListItem.length).to.equal(3);
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? I clearly have a `channelListItem` inside my `Channel` component:

```
return (
      <ChannelListItem  style={{paddingLeft: '0.8em', background: '#2E6DA4', height: '0.7em'}} channel={'aa'} key={'1'} onClick={::this.handleChangeChannel} />
);
```

Code for Channels:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ChannelListItem from './ChannelListItem';
import ChannelListModalItem from './ChannelListModalItem';
import { Modal, Glyphicon, Input, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as actions from '../actions/actions';
import uuid from 'node-uuid';
import { createChannel } from '../reducers/channels';
export default class Channels extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    channels: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    messages: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      addChannelModal: false,
      channelName: '',
      moreChannelsModal: false
    };
  }
  handleChangeChannel(channel) {
    if(this.state.moreChannelsModal) {
      this.closeMoreChannelsModal();
    }
    this.props.onClick(channel);
  }
  openAddChannelModal(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({addChannelModal: true});
  }
  closeAddChannelModal(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({addChannelModal: false});
  }
  handleModalChange(event) {
    this.setState({channelName: event.target.value});
  }
  handleModalSubmit(event) {
    const { channels, dispatch, socket } = this.props;
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.channelName.length < 1) {
      this.refs.channelName.getInputDOMNode().focus();
    }
    if (this.state.channelName.length > 0 && channels.filter(channel => {
      return channel.name === this.state.channelName.trim();
    }).length < 1) {
      const newChannel = {
        name: this.state.channelName.trim(),
        id: `${Date.now()}${uuid.v4()}`,
        private: false
      };
      dispatch(createChannel(newChannel));
      this.handleChangeChannel(newChannel);
      socket.emit('new channel', newChannel);
      this.setState({channelName: ''});
      this.closeAddChannelModal(event);
    }
  }
  validateChannelName() {

    const { channels } = this.props;

    if (channels.filter(channel => {
      return channel.name === this.state.channelName.trim();
    }).length > 0) {
      return 'error';
    }
    return 'success';
  }
  openMoreChannelsModal(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({moreChannelsModal: true});
  }
  closeMoreChannelsModal(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({moreChannelsModal: false});
  }
  createChannelWithinModal() {
    this.closeMoreChannelsModal();
    this.openAddChannelModal();
  }
  render() {
    const { channels, messages } = this.props;
    const filteredChannels = channels.slice(0, 8);
    const moreChannelsBoolean = channels.length > 8;
    const restOfTheChannels = channels.slice(8);
    const newChannelModal = (
      <div>
        <Modal key={1} show={this.state.addChannelModal} onHide={::this.closeAddChannelModal}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Add New Channel</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <form onSubmit={::this.handleModalSubmit} >
            <Input
              ref="channelName"
              type="text"
              help={this.validateChannelName() === 'error' && 'A channel with that name already exists!'}
              bsStyle={this.validateChannelName()}
              hasFeedback
              name="channelName"
              autoFocus="true"
              placeholder="Enter the channel name"
              value={this.state.channelName}
              onChange={::this.handleModalChange}
            />
            </form>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={::this.closeAddChannelModal}>Cancel</Button>
            <Button disabled={this.validateChannelName() === 'error' && 'true'} onClick={::this.handleModalSubmit} type="submit">
              Create Channel
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
      </div>
    );
    const moreChannelsModal = (
      <div style={{background: 'grey'}}>
        <Modal key={2} show={this.state.moreChannelsModal} onHide={::this.closeMoreChannelsModal}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton >
            <Modal.Title>More Channels</Modal.Title>
            <a onClick={::this.createChannelWithinModal} style={{'cursor': 'pointer', 'color': '#85BBE9'}}>
              Create a channel
            </a>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <ul style={{height: 'auto', margin: '0', overflowY: 'auto', padding: '0'}}>
              {restOfTheChannels.map(channel =>
                <ChannelListModalItem channel={channel} key={channel.id} onClick={::this.handleChangeChannel} />
                )}
            </ul>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <button onClick={::this.closeMoreChannelsModal}>Cancel</button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
    return (
      <section>
        <div>
          <span style={{paddingLeft: '0.8em', fontSize: '1.5em'}}>
            Channels
            <button onClick={::this.openAddChannelModal} style={{fontSize: '0.8em', 'background': 'Transparent', marginLeft: '2.8em', 'backgroundRepeat': 'noRepeat', 'border': 'none', 'cursor': 'pointer', 'overflow': 'hidden', 'outline': 'none'}}>
              <Glyphicon glyph="plus" />
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
          {newChannelModal}
        <div>
          <ul style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', listStyle: 'none', margin: '0', overflowY: 'auto', padding: '0'}}>
            {filteredChannels.map(channel =>
              <ChannelListItem  style={{paddingLeft: '0.8em', background: '#2E6DA4', height: '0.7em'}} messageCount={messages.filter(msg => {
                return msg.channelID === channel.name;
              }).length} channel={channel} key={channel.id} onClick={::this.handleChangeChannel} />
              )}
          </ul>
          {moreChannelsBoolean && <a onClick={::this.openMoreChannelsModal} style={{'cursor': 'pointer', 'color': '#85BBE9'}}> + {channels.length - 8} more...</a>}
          {moreChannelsModal}
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are doing everything right, could you please provide `< Channels>` code?

Comment: Well apparently the ChannelListItem is empty, so if you're expecting three channels to be in there then I'd investigate what is going wrong there. Might be a bug in the ChannelListItem component, might be something wrong with that fakeChannels data you're importing. Is it really correct that the file is called 'channelsFake' while the variable you use for it is 'fakeChannels' ?

Comment: I have added code for <Channels>, pls see above. Also tried to remove all the extraneous codes and just included a simple <ChannelListItem> component

Comment: Yes, fakeChannels and channelsFake are correct. They work fine in my other tests.